# tvOS: .hidden property on UIButton causing screen blur

Tags: swift, uibutton, hidden, tvos, apple-tv

Very weird. Xcode 7.1 Swift 2.1 tvOS
Whenever I try:

```
previousButton.hidden = false
```

the simulator screen goes all blurred.
Is this a bug or has tvOS some additional requirements hiding and showing UIButtons?

Comment: try `self.previousButton.enabled = NO;`                               `self.previousButton.title =  nil;`

Comment: there are no such properties for UIButton in tvOS